# spring junit testing with JMock

Tags: spring, junit, mocking, jmock

I have a Spring maven project and we are going to use JMock to test service/business/DAO layers of my project as suggested by client.
Can somebody please provide me the good link going through which I can understand and implement it? 
Also I have heard of other mocking frameworks like Mockito or EasyMock. Is JMock better than those? or Which one is better to use even? This is just for knowledge sake as I will be using JMock only since it is suggested by the client

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Junit testing using JMock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529616/spring-junit-testing-using-jmock)

Comment: not an exact duplicate..explanation is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was also posted to coderanch.com.  Copy/pasting my answer from there.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The official [getting started](http://www.jmock.org/getting-started.html) guide and [cookbook](http://www.jmock.org/cookbook.html) are good.

All three mock frameworks are good. At the moment, Mockito is somewhat more advanced. All three frameworks are still enhancing though. The next version of jMock catches up.